# RealmObject is not valid, so it cannot be copied

Tags: android, realm

Why is this code triggering a

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RealmObject is not valid, so it cannot be copied`

error?

```
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.delete(Booking.class);
final Booking booking = realm.copyFromRealm(
    new Booking(
        editFragment.getDestination(),
        editFragment.getDate()));
realm.commitTransaction();
```

However, if I change it to this the exception is not thrown:

```
realm.delete(Booking.class);
final Booking booking = realm.createObject(
    Booking.class,
    UUID.randomUUID().toString());
booking.setDestination(editFragment.getDestination());
booking.setDate(editFragment.getDate());
```

What is the difference?

The `Booking` class is defined as:

```
public class Booking extends RealmObject {

    @Required
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    @Required
    private String destination;

    @Required
    private Date date;

    private int status;
    private boolean isNotified;

    public Booking() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.status = STATUS_UNAVAILABLE;
    }

    public Booking(String destination, Date date) {
        this();
        this.destination = destination;
        this.date = date;
    }

    // Getters and setters follow
}
```

**Edit:**

Found what was wrong: I accidentally used `copyFromRealm` instead of `copyToRealm`. Looks like autocomplete sometimes works against you if you are not careful enough haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a valid RealmObject into copyFromRealm(..) It is not sufficient to create a new instance on the fly, because the new object won't be attached to Realm.

> Makes a standalone in-memory copy of an **already persisted** {@link RealmObject}.

In your second example you are creating a new object and passing it to the DB to be persisted: that are two very different operations.

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem - I used copy**From**Realm where I should have used copy**To**Realm.